# Native Table creation on top of GCS failed in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, ddl, google-cloud-storage

I tried to create a Big query native table on top of GCS bucket. The native table creation works, when the table is created from the UI, But when I tried to run DDL for creating a native table on top of GCS it Failed

Below is the query used and error produced:

create  table `sample_ds_001.native`
options
(
format='csv'
,uris=["gs://test-bucket-003/File_Folder/sample.txt"]
)

Error:
Unknown option: format at [4:3]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an external table for your requirement using the csv file stored in the gcs bucket, below query can be considered:

```
Create EXTERNAL table `project-id.dataset.table` 
options (format='csv' ,uris=["gs://file-location.csv"])
```

**CSV Data:**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
47803,000000000020030263,629,785,2021-01-12 23:26:37,986,2022-01-12 23:26:37
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Any idea on why the syntax is not working for native tables 
Note: I can create a native table on top of gcs location in web ui

Comment: Cloud storage is an external data source for BigQuery, so you won't be able to use native table to create a table using the file stored in gcs bucket. You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-table-definition) for more information.